# Improving Performance of Recursive CTE for calculating totals

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have a SQL Server database with an Employee table containing the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee 
(
    EmployeeID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    ManagerID INT,
    EmployeeName NVARCHAR(50),
    Salary DECIMAL(18, 2)
);
```

I'm using a recursive Common Table Expression (CTE) to calculate the total salaries of each employee and their subordinates. However, with a large number of employees, the query performance becomes sluggish.

```
WITH RecursiveSalaryCTE AS 
(
    SELECT 
        EmployeeID, ManagerID, EmployeeName, Salary
    FROM 
        Employee
    WHERE 
        ManagerID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        e.EmployeeID, e.ManagerID, e.EmployeeName, e.Salary
    FROM 
        Employee e
    JOIN 
        RecursiveSalaryCTE r ON e.ManagerID = r.EmployeeID
)
SELECT 
    EmployeeID, EmployeeName, Salary,
    (SELECT SUM(Salary) FROM RecursiveSalaryCTE 
     WHERE ManagerID = e.EmployeeID) AS TotalSubordinateSalaries
FROM 
    RecursiveSalaryCTE e;
```

Is there a better way to optimize this query? Any alternative approaches or modifications to the query that could provide faster results would greatly appreciated.

Example data for the `Employee` table:

```
INSERT INTO Employee (EmployeeID, ManagerID, EmployeeName, Salary)
VALUES (1, NULL, 'John', 10000.00),
       (2, 1, 'Alice', 7500.00),
       (3, 1, 'Bob', 8000.00),
       -- ... more data ...
       (1000, 999, 'Eve', 6000.00);
```

Comment: Please update your question with the output of the EXPLAIN PLAN for your query

Comment: SQL performance issues are often best analyzed by starting with the _actual execution plan_. Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question. Are there any indexes on the table?

Comment: This question needs details of your indexes/keys/constraints in addition to the table schema and the actual execution plan (paste the plan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using a sub-query as part of the final SELECT should improve performance and if you actually want the total of all people depending of a manager at any depth level you have to group by common path expression (thus you have to collect the path in the recursive CTE) ..., grouping by managerID gives you the total of direct subordinates only.

```
with RecursiveSalaryCTE(EmployeeID, managerid, salary, path) as (
    SELECT EmployeeID, managerid, Salary, cast(concat('/', EmployeeID) as varchar(1000))
    FROM employee
    WHERE managerid IS NULL
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT e.EmployeeID, e.managerid, e.salary, cast(concat(r.path, '/', e.EmployeeID) as varchar(1000))
    FROM employee e
    JOIN RecursiveSalaryCTE r ON e.managerid = r.EmployeeID

)
select EmployeeID, managerid, salary, Total_all_sub, 
    sum(salary) over(partition by managerid) as total_same_manager
from (
    select r.EmployeeID, r.managerid, r.salary,
        SUM(r1.Salary) Total_all_sub
    from RecursiveSalaryCTE r
    join RecursiveSalaryCTE r1 on substring(r1.path,1,len(r.path)) = r.path 
    group by r.EmployeeID, r.managerid, r.salary
) d
order by employeeid
;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/O1pMAy3p

Comment: You need to explain what you have done in the way of possible performance improvements - else this doesn't help OP design better queries.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://note.datengineer.dev/posts/recursive-ctes-and-connect-by-in-sql-to-query-hierarchical-data/#problem-2) suggested an elegant way to get the sum of subordinate salary. The idea is:

- First, explode the hierarchical structure to flattened table of all Manager-Employee pairs.
- Take the SUM with a simple GROUP BY

Below is the code (taken from the link, column name changed to fit your question)

```sql
WITH company_explode (ManagerID, EmployeeID, Salary, ManagementDistance) AS
(
    -- Base query. Select ALL employees
    SELECT 
        emp.ManagerID
        ,emp.EmployeeID
        ,emp.Salary
        ,1 AS ManagementDistance
    FROM EMPLOYEES emp
    
    UNION ALL
    
    -- Recursive query. Select ALL managers manages the employees
    SELECT
        mgr.ManagerID
        ,com.EmployeeID
        ,com.Salary
        ,com.ManagementDistance+1 AS ManagementDistance
    FROM EMPLOYEES mgr
    INNER JOIN company_explode com
        ON mgr.EmployeeID = com.ManagerID
)

SELECT ManagerID, SUM(Salary) AS TotalSubordinateSalary
FROM company_explode
GROUP BY ManagerID
```

This code use only 1 single Recursive CTE and 1 `GROUP BY`, no other sub-query that may slow down the code.

**Bonus**

The link also provide a shorter version for SQL that supports `CONNECT BY`. This very-short query is enough.

```sql
SELECT
    emp.MANAGER_ID
    ,SUM(CONNECT_BY_ROOT emp.SALARY) AS TOTAL_SALARY_MANAGED
FROM EMPLOYEES emp
CONNECT BY PRIOR emp.MANAGER_ID = emp.EMPLOYEE_ID
GROUP BY emp.MANAGER_ID
```